# Paypal Helper not Loading after upgrade, blank page

Tags: magento, paypal, helper

I upgraded Magento from v 1.4.x to 1.9.2.0. All seems to work OK except the Paypal module.

If I go to System -> Configuration in Admin, or the Checkout page on the front end, I get a blank screen.

The error_log shows this error when I go to System -> Configuration:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Paypal_Helper_Data::getConfigurationCountryCode() in /home/mysite/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Observer.php on line 130, referer: http://www.mysite.co.uk/index.php/site_admin/dashboard/index/key/7ec25272dd6e12345667015d73b305/
```

The error_log shows this when I go to the checkout on the front end:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'MERCHANT_COUNTRY_CONFIG_PATH' in /home/mysite/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Config.php on line 769, referer: http://www.mysite.co.uk/checkout/onepage/
```

All the files look to be present... specifically the Helper/Data.php file with the class Mage_Paypal_Helper_Data and getConfigurationCountryCode() method. So it seems its just not loading this helper class.

Does anyone have an idea why it would not load?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue. There was a Paypal folder with same `Mage_Paypal_Helper_Data` class in the `local/Mage` folder, but without the necessary methods. This class was therefore being loaded. The class must have been left over in 1.4.x in which it somehow worked. Removing this folder results in the `core/Mage/Paypal` class working.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem too, though I was getting a different error after upgrading to `1.9.2.2`.

When I clicked to checkout with paypal express, it would bring up an error page:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::setIsBml() in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php on line 98.

After banging my head against a wall for some time, I finally checked the `local/mage` folder and discovered a checkout override for paypal that had been done by a previous developer 18 months ago. Makes sense that the error came up after the upgrade, as the override was for an older version of magento's paypal setup.

Delete the override, fixed done and sorted!

Cheers